# The anime downloader

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium

> [NOTE: Here's the latest version of this program, since this question idled out.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231064/anipop-the-anime-downloader)

This is a recreational script made to update my home server w/ the latest anime from [HorribleSubs](https://horriblesubs.info/). I'd like to know if there are any obvious syntactical and performance improvements, details on my usage of Selenium and BS4 and whether or not this usage is proper. More features will be added later, but as it as now I feel there are ways to improve it. One idea I've had is to install uBlock Origin on the browser instance to decrease the number of elements to iterate over, but I don't know if this would be significant.

#### Windows Setup

1. Install [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/) to install any necessary programs.
2. Run the following commands for whatever you don't have installed:

   ```bsh
   scoop bucket add extras
   scoop install python geckodriver qbittorrent
   pip install beautifulsoup4 selenium python-qbittorrent
   ```
3. Enable the qBittorrent [web interface](https://github.com/lgallard/qBittorrent-Controller/wiki/How-to-enable-the-qBittorrent-Web-UI).

#### Le Code

```py
import urllib.request as Web
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from qbittorrent import Client

qb = Client('http://127.0.0.1:8080/')
# 'Bypass from localhost' should be enabled

# TODO: Check if this drive is full, and switch to an available one
DL_PATH = "E:/Torrents/"
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
req = Web.Request('https://horriblesubs.info/current-season/', headers=headers)
src = Web.urlopen(req).read()
parser = bs4(src, features='html.parser')
divs = parser.body.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'ind-show'})
size = len(divs)

for i, div in enumerate(divs):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://horriblesubs.info' + div.a['href'])
    WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'rls-info-container')))

    # Expand the whole listing to get all the episodes
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('show-more')
    while elem.text != 'No more results':
        elem.click()
        elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('show-more')

    src = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    parser = bs4(src, features='html.parser')
    hs = parser.body\
        .find('div', attrs={'class': 'hs-shows'})\
        .find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'rls-info-container'})

    for block in hs:
        # TODO: If a resolution is updated, delete the lower resolution alternative on disk
        link_rel = block.find('div', attrs={'class': 'rls-link link-1080p'})

        if (link_rel is None):
            link_rel = block.find('div', attrs={'class': 'rls-link link-720p'})

        if (link_rel is None):
            link_rel = block.find('div', attrs={'class': 'rls-link link-480p'})

        if (link_rel is not None):
            magnet = link_rel.find('a', attrs={'title': 'Magnet Link'})['href']
            qb.download_from_link(magnet, category='anime', savepath=DL_PATH + div.a.text)

    print('Progress: ' + str(round(((i + 1) / size) * 100, 2)) + '%')
```