# How to write a multivariate multi-step forecasting from a multivariate single step

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, machine-learning

I'm trying to implement a multi-variate, multiple-step model to forecast the day ahead electricity prices (h+1,h+2,...,h+24). I know how to do one forecast, but I'm confused with how to implement a multiple output approach where each forecast gives a vector of predictions for each hour in the day head for one shot (the multiple output strategy in https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-step-time-series-forecasting/).

The gist of what I've done is get the code that predicts one time step, and modify it by converting the output into a sequence for the next 24 hours time shift, instead of just say one ElecPrice shifted 24 hours into the future:

```
Y['ElecPrice1'] = df['RT_LMP'].shift(-1)
Y['ElecPrice2'] = df['RT_LMP'].shift(-2)
Y['ElecPrice3'] = df['RT_LMP'].shift(-3)
...
Y['ElecPrice3'] = df['RT_LMP'].shift(-24)
```

I also changed the number of output signals my model has to predict.

Basically I made an entire 24 new columns instead of just one for my predictions. I have adjusted my dataset accordingly (no dangling NaNs, etc.). It seems too simple that I'm worrying if all I'm doing is making a prediction for one hour and copying that for the rest of the hours.

The sample code can be viewed in this link https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Joichiro666/Forecasting-sharing/blob/master/LSTM-DNN%203.ipynb (ignore anything below generate predictions)

I just want to confirm if what I'm doing is correct or not.

Comment: I could show you how to automate the creation of all the `Y['ElecPrice3'] = df['RT_LMP'].shift(-24)` lines, but if you aren't sure if the code is correct, it isn't on topic here.

Comment: Yes, please. And, yes I'm also not sure if its correct - is there a more correct board for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to my recent review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231064/anipop-the-anime-downloader/231067#231067), you can automate the simple repetition of each line by thinking about what's the same in each line, and what's different.

Each line seems to be, essentially:

```
Y['ElecPriceN'] = df['RT_LMP'].shift(-N)
```

The only thing that changes each time is `N`, so just loop over a `range` that generates numbers:

```
for n in range(1, 25):  # range(24) if you started at 0 instead of 1
    Y['ElecPrice' + str(n)] = df['RT_LMP'].shift(-n)
```

- Construct a key string by taking `n`, stringifying it using `str`, then concatenating it to the name.
- Generate a `shift` value by just negating `n`. `-n` is the same as `n * -1`.

---

As for "I just want to confirm if what I'm doing is correct or not.", that's offtopic here, and too broad of a question for anywhere on Stack Exchange. A broad site like Reddit may be able to help you though.